# How to develop chrome extension for continuous screenshot capture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop screen capture (tab capture) chrome extension where my goal is to get the screen shot every second, save it and display it in html element. I followed and tried some tutorials but wasn't able to achieve this requirement. Below are the codes:
manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "screen control",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "111 basic example extension with only required keys",
    "icons": {
      "16": "asd.png",
      "48": "asd.png",
      "128": "asd.png"
    },
    "action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/not-recording.png",
      "default_title": "Click Me",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "permissions": ["storage", "alarms", "notifications", "activeTab"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
  }
```

background.js :

```
chrome.alarms.create({ periodInMinutes: 1 / 60 });

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(async (alarm) => {
    // Get the active tab
    const tab = await getActiveTab();
    
    // Capture the tab
    const dataUrl = await captureTab(tab.id);
    
    // Save the screenshot in chrome.storage.sync
    saveScreenshot(dataUrl);
});

function getActiveTab() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
            if (tabs && tabs.length > 0) {
                resolve(tabs[0]);
            } else {
                reject("No active tab found.");
            }
        });
    });
}

function captureTab(tabId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.tabs.capture(tabId, { format: "png" }, (dataUrl) => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                reject(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            } else {
                resolve(dataUrl);
            }
        });
    });
}

function saveScreenshot(dataUrl) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["screenshots"], (res) => {
        const screenshots = res.screenshots || [];
        screenshots.push(dataUrl);

        chrome.storage.sync.set({ screenshots });
    });
}
```

popup.js :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    displayScreenshots();

    setInterval(displayScreenshots, 1000); // Update screenshots every second
});

function displayScreenshots() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["screenshots"], (res) => {
        const screenshots = res.screenshots || [];
        const screenshotsContainer = document.getElementById("screenshotsContainer");

        // Clear previous screenshots
        screenshotsContainer.innerHTML = "";

        // Display screenshots
        screenshots.forEach((dataUrl) => {
            const img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = dataUrl;
            screenshotsContainer.appendChild(img);
        });
    });
}
```

I am new to chrome extension development and not aware of many things. Is there anyway to achieve this requirement ?